# How to convert 4 dimensional matrix to NHWC format in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

So I'm in the middle of implementing SIFT and the thing is that I don't know how to deal with channel in OpenCV. Here is what I've done so far.

```cpp
#ifndef QUANTIZATION_DATABASE_DATA_READ_H
#define QUANTIZATION_DATABASE_DATA_READ_H
// C HEADERS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
// C++ HEADERS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// OPENCV HEADERS
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace cv
{
    class DataReader
    {
    public:

        explicit DataReader(int _flags) : flags(_flags)
        {

        }

        void read(std::string filename, const char *key, Mat &res)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::Mode::FORMAT_XML | FileStorage::Mode::READ);
                fs[key] >> res;
                fs.release();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                std::cerr << e.msg << std::endl;
            }

        }

    private:
        int flags;
    };
}
```

The algorithm that I want to implement is as follow.

1. Read the 4 dimensional matrix(NHWC) from a xml file.
2. Store it in a matrix
3. Convert it into NHWC

The thing is that I don't have to do step 3 when I do some stuffs using Tensorflow. It just automatically knows the last dimension is channel. So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no way whatsoever to make 4 dimensional buffer to a batch of images. So I decided to change the format of the xml file and it worked like a charm.

Below is temporarily workaround for this problem.

```
#ifndef QUANTIZATION_DATABASE_DATA_READ_H
#define QUANTIZATION_DATABASE_DATA_READ_H
// C HEADERS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
// C++ HEADERS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// OPENCV HEADERS
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace cv
{
    class DataReader
    {
    public:

        explicit DataReader(int _flags) : flags(_flags)
        {

        }

        void read(std::string filename, Mat &res)
        {
            try
            {
                float length = 0;

                FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::Mode::FORMAT_XML | FileStorage::Mode::READ);

                fs["size"] >> length;
                for (int i = 0; i < (int)length; ++i) {
                    std::string key("image");
                    std::string index = std::to_string(i);
                    Mat image;

                    key = key + index;
                    fs[key.c_str()] >> image;
                    std::cout << image.channels() << std::endl;
                    res.push_back(image);
                }

                fs.release();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                std::cerr << e.msg << std::endl;
            }

        }

    private:
        int flags;
    };
}
```